# How to process excel file in vb.net without office installed

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-office

I am fairly new to VB.net and never used it for processing Office files.
Right now I have to look at Excel file and send some emails based on the data in the cells. I do not need to write anything to these files.
So far I have read quite a bit about PIAs and so far it looks that I have to design my application for particular Office version? 
Is there a way to write the application which could handle files created by different versions of MS Excel?
I would like to be able to process these files without Office being installed on the computer at all, is there any way to do it?

Comment: What formats do you need to support? Anything that Excel does? Only certain versions of Excel? Keep in mind that the older versions used exclusively the XLS format, which is essentially a binary dump of Excel's internal data structures. Parsing this without rewriting Excel will be exceedingly difficult. The newer versions use the XLSX format, which are basically ZIP files that contain XML files. This is much easier to parse, if you can guarantee it's the only input you'll receive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> Don't need to install Office for getting data from excel file.

But for getting data from EXCEL fileyou have to install  OLEDB driver in your local machine as well as server if you are hosted your application on server.

> You can download OLEDB driver from [MICROSOFT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23734).

```
 con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + YourEXCELFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

con.Open()
atatable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
sheetname = datatable.Rows(0)("table_name").ToString
excelcomm = New OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetname + "]", con)
adexcel = New OleDbDataAdapter(excelcomm)
adexcel.Fill(Dataset)
```

After this code you will get excel sheet data in dataset.

Might this code can help you to get data from excel file.

(NOTE:this code is in vb.net)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

1. [npoi](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)
2. [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

   which do not require excel

Comment: +1 For EPPlus. This is the main library I use. I find it easy to use and it does most things I need it to. It doesn't have the performance issues I've experienced with the OLEDB driver.

Comment: Since I need to process .xls files I decided to use excellibrary and it works great so far. Was thinking about using NPOI but read somewhere it is not very "user friendly", might give it a shot for next project.