# C# - delete Excel-row wihout using the Interop namespace

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, office-interop

I am searching a C# way to delete (empty) Excel-rows in a worksheet without using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.

Found many examples with the Interop namespace like [C# and excel deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255166/c-sharp-and-excel-deleting-rows) . But is there a way to do it without third-party-tools - only with the .NET?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not clear whether you mean you want to do this without using the Excel application, or wehther you simply want to manipulate the workbook in Excel but without a reference to the PIAs/COM libraries. Both are possible - without using third-party tools, but the approaches are very different

Comment: In my case, the best solution would be without any third party-tools and references. Only the NET. Added it to the question!

Comment: You still haven't answered my question: Should your solution work with the Excel application ("interop") or not? Asked another way: Will this be in a server environment? Can you count on the Excel application being present?

Comment: No, ... I can't count on the Interop ... Excel is not there.

Answer (score 1):

The options for working with Excel files relying only on standard .NET Framework namespaces is limited. Two possibilities come to mind. The first is "simplest", but only applicable if your main interest is in working with the content as a database. The second allows you to do pretty much "anything" with the Excel workbook, but the learning curve will be steep.

Both of these approaches are suited for working in a server environment (unlike those that require presence of the Excel application) and do not require any licenses.

1. You can use an OLE DB connection (ACE OLE DB provider) to communicate with the contents of an Excel workbook. It allows connecting to individual worksheets as well as named ranges. Basic SQL functionality is supported.
2. The file format of Excel 2007 and later versions is Office Open XML (OOXML). These files are "zip packages" containing the files (xml for the most part) that make up a workbook. So any standard tools that can work with Zip packages and XML can be used to open up an Excel workbook, edit the content, then close the workbook back up. In the .NET Framework, these would be the System.IO.Packaging (in WindowsBase.dll, usually needs to be referenced specifically) and System.XML namespaces.

   The documentation for the file formats is the ECMA-376 standard (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). A useful on-line resource is openxmldeveloper.org.

   Note that Microsoft also provides the Open XML SDK, a free download which can be distributed license-free with your solution. The Open XML SDK reduces the "learning curve" as it reduces the amount of knowledge you need about the OOXML file formats. I mention this for the sake of completeness, because I know how challenging trying to work directly with the file format is. Also, since the DLL is freely distributable and can be copied as part of your solution it might meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow post may help - it discusses some libraries that can manipulate excel without needing Office installed.
The question regards VB.NET but I believe the options discussed would work with C# too...

[How to process excel file in vb.net without office installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419834/how-to-process-excel-file-in-vb-net-without-office-installed)